# XQUERY XML запрос

Tags: sql, xml, запрос, xquery

Имею таблицу, в которой единственный столбец типа XMLTYPE(Таблица - `XTable`, столбец - `v`).
Все записи в данном столбце имеют структуру:

```
<main>
   <type1>
      <element>
         <param1>...</param1>
         <param2>...</param2>
         <param3>...</param3>
      </element>
      <element>
         <param1>...</param1>
         <param2>...</param2>
         <param3>...</param3>
      </element>
      .
      .
      .
   </type1>
</main>
```

Выполняя такой запрос:

```
select XmlColumn.query('.') as elements
from XTable cross apply XTable.v.nodes('/main/type1/element') AS AdditionalTable(XmlColumn)
```

Выводит:

`<element><param1>..</param1><param2>..</param2><param3>..</param3></element>`

Но как хочу разделить все по 3 графам:

```
select  XmlColumn.value('/main/type1/element/param1', 'nvarchar(max)') as param1,
        XmlColumn.value('/main/type1/element/param2', 'nvarchar(max)') as param2,
        XmlColumn.value('/main/type1/element/param3', 'nvarchar(max)') as param3
from XTable cross apply XTable.v.nodes('/main/type1/element/') AS AdditionalTable(XmlColumn)
```

Получаю ошибку:

> XQuery [XTable.v.value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'

Каким образом я могу разбить верхнее выражение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  XmlColumn.value('./param1[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as param1,
        XmlColumn.value('./param2[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as param2,
        XmlColumn.value('./param3[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as param3
from XTable cross apply XTable.v.nodes('/main/type1/element') AS AdditionalTable(XmlColumn)
```

В выражении `nodes` уже выбран узел `element`, поэтому в `value` нужно вести отсчёт от текущего узла, что обозначается точкой: `.`.

Селектор `[1]` нужен, т. к. дочерних узлов может быть более одного и нужно указать, из какого берётся значение.